# how to change the string array of a spinner at runtimeHow to use the selected item of a spinner in an if statement (Android in eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, spinner

Hi I have a spinner (spinner1) and when the user selects an item from it (example: "Canada" I want the spinner2 to populate with Provinces of "canada". I have tried the following but it doesnt work. I tried to do this by using:

```
if (spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Canada"))
{
    addItemsOnSpinner2();
}

public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

  spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add("Item 1");
    list.add("Item 2");
    list.add("Item 3");
    list.add("Item 4");
    ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

}

for some reason the items aren't being added to spinner2. please help

Comment: What isn't working? Nothing is being populated in `spinner2`? Where is this code located?

Comment: the if statement is in private void onCreate

Comment: Shouldn't that be in `onItemSelected()` from `spinner1`? That is only going to run the first time the `Activity` is created.

Comment: right now when i load the app, spinner2 is blank. when i click one of the items in spinner1 i want spinner2 to get populated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code

```
    if (spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Canada"))
    {
        addItemsOnSpinner2();
    }
```

will only run the first time the `Activity` is created since it is in your `onCreate()`. You need to add this code to your `onItemSelected()` for `spinner1`. So you first need to implement an `OnItemSelected` `listener` to that `spinner`.

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelected(new OnItemSelected()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, 
                                    long id) 
    {
         TextView tv = (TextView)v;   // cast the View to a TextView
         if ("Canada".equals(tv.getText().toString())
         {
            addItemsOnSpinner2();   
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }
});
```

Something like this should work. Although, you will probably be safer to use `position` instead of getting the text.

[OnItemSelected Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html)

Comment: when i put this code in, i get this error:                      Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert ") Statement" to complete IfStatement
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation

Comment: im also getting error after (TextView)v :"The local variable v may not have been initialized". also is it TextView tv or TextView v.

Comment: Check it again. Sorry, I was rushing and used the wrong variable name

Comment: where am i suppose to add this part: spinner1.setOnItemSelected(new OnItemSelected()
{. i keep getting errors

Comment: You can put that in `onCreate()` after you initialize your `spinner`. I don't know what your errors are but they should tell you what the issue is